# allow-origin not working for multiple domains on apache2

Tags: apache, proxy, cors, access-control

I am trying to allow only certain domains to access the source. When I am inserting

`Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "domain.tld"` it works perfectly.

When I try it for multiple domains, it does the **opposite**. It allows any domain but not `cors.domain.tld`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9090/

    ServerName map.domain.tld
    ServerAlias map.domain.tld

    <Proxy *>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(cors.domain.tld|staging.google.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        Header merge Vary Origin       
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>    

</VirtualHost>
```

What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to set --no-cors on the my docker image, where I proxy the domain to. Now it works fine.